# C program: Simple math program

Tags: c

**Want to print for example 
  Grade: 4/5
  80 percent**
Program ask a user how many math problems they want to solve and prints out the number of "wrongs/the number of rights" and their grade. I think I dont have my math right at the end of the code cause its printing out for example:
  Grade: 4/5
  -7446528 percent

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int NumberOfTimes, AddAns, SubAns, AddCorrect=0, SubCorrect=0, CorrectAnsAdd, CorrectAnsSub, TotalCorrect, TotalWrong, Add;
    int i,a,b,c,d,e,f,g;
    float percent;

    printf("\n");
    printf("-------------------MATH QUIZ------------------------\n");
    printf("Enter the number of Math problems you want to solve:"); //enters the # of problems the program produces
    scanf("%d", &NumberOfTimes);
    printf("\n");
    srand(time(NULL));
    //Random number generator
    for (i=0;i<NumberOfTimes;++i)
    {
        b = rand() %3 + 1;
        c = rand() %3 + 1;
        a = rand() %2 + 1;

        //Random addition problems
        if (a == 1)
        {
            printf("%d + %d = ", b,c);
            scanf("%d", &AddAns);
            d = b + c;
            if (AddAns == d)
            {
                printf("  +Correct\n");
                AddCorrect = AddCorrect + 1;
            }
            //Random subtraction problems
            else
            {
                printf("  +Wrong, it was %d\n", d);
                AddIncorrect = AddIncorrect + 1;
            }
        }
        if (a == 2)
        {
            printf("%d - %d = ", b,c);
            scanf("%d", &SubAns);
            g = b - c;
            //Produces right or wrong answers
            if (SubAns == g)
            {
               printf("  +Correct\n");
               SubCorrect = SubCorrect + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("  +Wrong, it was %d\n", g);
                SubIncorrect = SubIncorrect + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    //Producing the output to wrong/right numbers and grade percentage 
    TotalCorrect = AddCorrect + SubCorrect;
    printf("\n");
    printf("Grade: %d/%d\n",TotalCorrect,NumberOfTimes);
    printf("\n");
    percent=NumberOfTimes/TotalCorrect;
    printf("%d percent \n", percent);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `%f` to print float value. I.e. `printf("%f percent \n", percent);`.

Comment: Your calculation for percentage is wrong... should be number correct divided by number of questions, not the other way around... and it needs to be multiplied by 100, and something in there needs to be `float` so it won't be calculated with integer division.  Also you need the `%f` format specifier to print it, not `%d` which is for integers.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking about. Questions usually end with `?`. Read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on. First, to print a `float` with `printf`, use `%f`. `%d` is for `int`s.

Secondly, when you calculate `percent`, you're accidentally using integer division. Since `NumberOfTimes` and `TotalCorrect` are both integers, `NumberOfTimes/TotalCorrect` performs integer division and produces an `int`. It's only converted to a `float` *after* the whole initializing expression is evaluated. Use this instead:

```
percent = (float)TotalCorrect / NumberOfTimes;
// OR, if you want an actual percent:
percent = 100.0f*TotalCorrect/NumberOfTimes;
```

Then, using `%f`:

```
printf("%f percent\n", percent); // "80.000000 percent"
```

Note that this will display the percentage out to many decimal places; if you want a cleaner display without a decimal point, you could just calculate the percent as an `int`:

```
// multiply before dividing to avoid integer division problems
int percent = 100*TotalCorrect/NumberOfTimes;
printf("%d percent\n", percent); // "80 percent"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In C, dividing two integers won't get you a floating point number, even if the assignment is to a float. It's just how the language works. You'll have to cast NumberOfTimes and TotalCorrect as floats.

So replace 
`percent=NumberOfTimes/TotalCorrect;` with

```
percent=(float)TotalCorrect/(float)NumberOfTimes * 100;
```

Furthermore, you're trying to print a float as an integer in the line

```
printf("%d percent \n", percent);
```

which is giving you a wonky result. Instead, try:

```
printf("%d percent \n", (int)percent);
```

Comment: Casting one of them will do... the other will be converted automatically.  Or move multiply to the front and use a `float` literal (`100f`) instead of an `int` one.